# SharpRepository + OptimisticConcurrency

Tags: ravendb, sharp-repository

Wondering if there is any way to set the save/update operation of a repository to use optimistic concurrency?  Haven't seen any method to do this?  Or maybe it's configured this way by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the RaveDbRepository based on the question.

Unfortunately, right now there isn't a way to do that.  Many of the RavenDb specific needs can't currently be addressed through using SharpRepository to interface with it, but we would like to get to that point.

Currently, a document store is used to instantiate the RavenDbRepository which is then used to create the IDocumentSession (by calling documentStore.OpenSession()).  Since the flag for using optimistic concurrency is on the session itself there currently isn't a great way to handle this.

Please post an issue on GitHub for us about this and we'll look into making it happen.  Off the top of my head we have some options:

- Allow public or protected access to IDocumentSession so that you could access the session directly or in an inherited class and set that flag.
- Allow the ability to instantiate a RavenDbRepository from a IDocumentSesison instead of a DocumentStore, so that the settings could be made while creating the repository.
- Somehow work these into the default conventions, though I'm not sure how.

Comment: In my Repository that inherits from the IRepository<TEntity, TKey> Can't I just implement a custom method sig in there? then implement that in the class(es) that implement the custom interface?

Comment: If you use the latest bits from GitHub (not available on NuGet yet), I just made DocumentStore and Session protected so that in your specific Repository that inherits from RavenDbRepository, you can access the Session and set the optimistic concurrency flag there.  In the constructor you would first call the base constructor in order to initialize the session, and then set Session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true

Comment: Or instead of the constructor, you can use a custom method as you say, but you'll still need to use the latest source from GitHub to get access to the Session so you can set the appropriate flag.